# DB2 AS/400: Different System Name and SQL Name of 10 chars for table

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

If you create an SQL-table on an AS/400 (iSeries, System i, ...) the table gets an SQL name (up to 128 chars) and a system name (up to 10 chars). If the SQL name is too long, a system name is generated. You can change the sql name (via `RENAME TABLE x TO y`) and the system name (via `RENAME TABLE x TO SYSTEM NAME y`) independently.

That is, you can do that, if the SQL name is longer than 10 chars. If it is 10 chars or shorter, the system name is changed along automatically, and I cannot manage to change the two to different values of 10 or less chars.

`RENAME TABLE x TO y FOR SYSTEM NAME z` does not work, while `RENAME TABLE x TO y1234567890 FOR SYSTEM NAME z` does work.

Is there a way to get it done? And if there is, how?

If not, that is an answer, too - would mean my only way to fulfil both our SQL- and physical file naming schemes is to use extra longer long names, even though it makes no sense (and does not go along with my Java-Entities).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do what you want.

The create table syntax:

```
>>-CREATE--+------------+--TABLE--table-name--+-------------------------------------------+-->
           '-OR REPLACE-'                     '-FOR SYSTEM NAME--system-object-identifier-'
```

May make you job a bit easier as you don't have to rename the table later, but still:

> **FOR SYSTEM NAME system-object-identifier** 
>    Identifies the system-object-identifier of the table. system-object-identifier must not be the same as a table, view, alias, or index that already exists at the current server. The system-object-identifier must be an unqualified system identifier.
>   When system-object-identifier is specified, table-name must not be a valid system object name.

Thus if the table name would normally be a valid IBM i system name, you can't use `FOR SYSTEM NAME`.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. Guess I'll have to live with it.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider just creating the table with one short name, and creating an `ALIAS` with the other short name.